# Grant select previleges to a synonym

Tags: oracle, plsql, synonym

--I'm using a view named `V_AREA` and it's `SYNONYM`: `AREA`
However, when I try to grant select permissions to my role, I get the following error:

> GRANT SELECT ON AREA TO MY_ROLE
>
> - ERROR at line 1: ORA-02225: only EXECUTE and DEBUG privileges are valid for procedures

I'm not using a procedure, what can I do?

I've tryed to use the following grants:

```
Grant select on area to my_role; --this one gives the above error
Grant select on 'area' to my_role; --this gives other error 
Grant select on "area" to my_role; --this gives the same error as 'area'
```

**EDIT:**

I have 2 synonyms created named AREA: one to my view `V_AREA` and other to `OGC_AREA`. No procedures involved

Comment: What's returned if you execute `SELECT * FROM ALL_PROCEDURES WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'AREA'`?

Comment: @BobJarvis nothing is returned

Comment: You need to grant the `select` privilege on the _view_, not on the synonym.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

grant references to the user on all the base tables used in the view using this

```
Grant references on your_schema.tablename to target_schema or user;
```

Comment: the `references` privileges is for creating foreign keys. You need to grant `select` on the view.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Correct, but if different schemas are involved with views in one schema and tables in another this has worked for me